# Convert NULL into empty string while getting response

Tags: php, database, laravel, equivalent

i just want how can we convert null into empty string while getting result from db.
For example

```
User::first();
```

In user table, roll number is null value. i want it to convert into empty string.

Comment: do you need all response `NULL` to `""` for android or iphone developer ?

Comment: Yes for iphone developer

Comment: then use middleware and apply to all route so you will not miss any where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in boot method with retrieved observer like this.

```
 self::retrieved(function ($model) {
        $keys = $model->fillable;
        foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
            $model->attributes[$value] = @$model->attributes[$value] == null ?  '' : $model->attributes[$value];
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

i had same task i solved this by Middleware

created  `NullToBlank.php` Middleware

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class NullToBlank
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $output = $next($request);
        if ($output) {

            $json = $output->content();
            $modelAsArray = json_decode($json, true);

            if (is_array($modelAsArray)) {
                array_walk_recursive($modelAsArray, function (&$item, $key) {
                    $item = $item === null ? '' : $item;
                });
                return response($modelAsArray);
            } else {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then apply this middleware whenever you need to replace `NULL` to `""`